# Live Video editor error (employer cannot decode to ping)

Tags: apt, updates, video

I have installed the live video editor by [this site instruction](https://www.ubuntupit.com/top-10-best-video-editing-software-ubuntu-install/) and this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/lives
sudo apt update
sudo apt install lives
```

so when I try to run it, I get this error:
[image]

so I have tried to remove the player and reinstall it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mplayer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdirectfb-1.7-7 libenca0 libvorbisidec1 linux-headers-5.0.0-32
  linux-headers-5.0.0-32-generic linux-image-5.0.0-32-generic
  linux-modules-5.0.0-32-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mplayer*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
After this operation, 5,065 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 333255 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mplayer (2:1.3.0-7build2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
(Reading database ... 333227 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for mplayer (2:1.3.0-7build2) ...
so@so-notebook:/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/Programer/VmWare$  rm -r ~/.mplayer/
so@so-notebook:/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa/Softwares/Linux's/Programer/VmWare$ sudo aptitude install mplayer
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mplayer 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,215 kB of archives. After unpacking 5,065 kB will be used.
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
Selecting previously unselected package mplayer.
(Reading database ... 333224 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mplayer_2%3a1.3.0-7build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mplayer (2:1.3.0-7build2) ...
Setting up mplayer (2:1.3.0-7build2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
```

but the error still resists!!

thanks for your attention.

Comment: I'd suggest cleaning up your sources; removing the duplicates..  I'm sorry I don't actually see the issue, but I'm somewhat distracted by the *lack of maintenance*

Comment: i don't get the relation between this and that, but i asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196091/must-i-cut-some-duplicate-entry-from-system-settings-software-and-updates) another question for undrestanding more ...

Comment: Also, to fix your `apt` error, you need to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and the error says that the universe repository is listed twice in this file on line 43 and line 48. You need to either remove the word "universe" from one of these lines or remove one of these lines if universe is the only repo listed on the line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is kind of a dummy error. First of all, the current version of `mplayer` *does* have the ability to decode `png` (mplayer uses libpng; I have the libpng packages and libpng-tools installed and I still get the error and I tested mplayer with png files and it does decode). Next, looking at one of the [source files for lives](https://fossies.org/linux/LiVES/po/en_GB.po) it seems that there is another error message on line 1110 that states: *"You should install mplayer with either png/alpha or jpeg support".*

It appears that you need either jpeg *or* png/alpha support.

Unless you end up with some unwanted behavior or are missing some capability, you should be able to ignore this error.