# Must i cut some duplicate entry from System settings >> Software and Updates >> Other Software from the list?

Tags: duplicate

I have some duplicated entry like this :

[image]

so must it be delete some entry which duplicated by end text:**... main** and **... main source Code**?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I see only one duplicate entry, but it is disabled.

Comment: so it is OK and no need to delete the not signed entry form list,am i right?

Comment: You can delete the one duplicate source code entry, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: so how flag my question as solved?

Comment: I can write is aa an answer, then you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only one duplicate entry: `teejee2008` source code.

It is disabled, so it doesn't really matters if you delete it or not.

Others are not duplicate.